# List names of partitioned tables and names of partitions separately

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have created a database with non-partitioned tables and partitioned tables with their partitions as following:

```
 Schema |      Name       |       Type        |     Owner
--------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------
 public | cust_arr_large  | table             | admin
 public | cust_arr_medium | table             | admin
 public | cust_arr_small  | table             | admin
 public | customers       | partitioned table | admin
 public | company         | table             | admin
 public | industry        | table             | admin
```

The above table is the display of this command `\dt`.

Tables `company` and `industry` are regular tables with no partition. Table `customers` is a partitioned table and `cust_arr_large`, `cust_arr_medium`  and `cust_arr_small` are its partitions.

Using SQL commands, how do I :

1 - List only the names of the regular tables and the parent partitioned tables (i.e. `company`, `industry` and `customers`)

2 - List only the partitions (i.e. `cust_arr_small`, `cust_arr_medium` and `cust_arr_large`).

I am looking for a SQL-syntax so that I can use it in a `psycopg2` script in Python. I need the lists for further work in Python.

Comment: `\dP` gives the partitioned tables

Answer (score 0):

`\dPn` returns a list of the partitioned relations if thats what youre asking

also, `\dP` lists only the partition tables

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this using SQL?